# Autodesk Maya & OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl

Может ли движок написанный при помощи OpenGL EC загружать/использовать графические модели, нарисованные в редакторе Maya?

Answer (score 4):

Может. Но загрузку моделей вам придётся писать руками. И, конечно, будут ограничения: нельзя ждать от мобильной графики фонтанирующей производительности.

Comment: Возможно есть более подходящий под OpenGL 3D редактор?

Comment: Мухи - отдельно, котлеты - отдельно. Редактор (с точки зрения вашей 3D модели) ничего не знает ни об OpenGL ни о DirectX.

Answer (score 1):

Может, потому что вы напишите загрузку моделей из удобного вам формата. OpenGL в любом случае не умеет непосредственно работать с моделями ни из 3DS MAX, ни из Maya, ни из Blender'a.

Довольно несложно (и недолго) написать самому, например, загрузку формата OBJ.